# Using leaflet with large data - ACS data for all counties in U.S

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm plotting ACS data (counts of low-income children) for each county across the entire U.S. I don't have any markers, just a county shapefile and 6 values for each county that are in separate layers.

Unsurprisingly this is too large for browsers to handle. I've seen some similar questions here that deal with clustering, but since I have nothing to cluster I'm starting a new question.

I've tried breaking it up into 6 regional maps, but even those are too much.

Is there some way to lower the footprint, but still have all the county specific data?

I've looked at tilemill and other options for only loading the data the user is currently viewing and based on the zoom level, but I can't find any information on how to go from an R generated leaflet map to something like that. Alternatives using this route are useful as well.

Comment: I am assuming with 'county shapefile' you mean polygon data? How bout reading these layers and `cbind`ing them into one (assuming the geometry is constant across the layers). If that is not sufficient, you can try to simplify the polygons using the [rmapshaper package](https://github.com/ateucher/rmapshaper) and then try visualising it with [mapview](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview). The former will help get rid of 'unnecessary' polygon vertices, while the latter has dedicated functions to enable leaflet rendering of large data (ballpark around 100k features - depending on complexity).

Comment: Are you suggesting that leaflet makes 6 copies of the polygons when I add 6 layers to my map?  You are correct that the geometry is the same in each layer.  The only difference depending on which layer is being viewed is the popup and the fillColor.  If this is the case, I'm surprised that leaflet would be so inefficient. Looking at the `addPolgygons` function, I don't see an obvious way to separate the data from the geometry.  Can anyone suggest how to change this behavior in leaflet?

Comment: leaflet doesn't do anything but render your data on a map. The step that is determining how many layers you are dealing with is the `rgdal::readOGR` or `sf::st_read` part. When you say 6 layers I am assuming 6 layers (each with their own geometry). If you are referring to one layer with 6 attribute table columns then geometry is only needed once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to simplify the polygons using the [rmapshaper package](https://github.com/ateucher/rmapshaper) and then try visualising it with [mapview](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview). The former will help get rid of 'unnecessary' polygon vertices, while the latter has dedicated functions to enable leaflet rendering of large data (ballpark around 100k features - depending on complexity).

Comment: rmapshaper did the trick! I didn't need to use mapview. I used rmapshaper::ms_simplify(mydata) where mydata was the Large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame generated from geo_join()

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider the **tigris** package, which gets you direct access to low-resolution county shapefiles within R:

```
library(tigris)
library(leaflet)

cty <- counties(cb = TRUE, resolution = "20m")

leaflet(cty) %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons()
```

This should allow your Leaflet map to perform well in-browser as the polygons are pre-simplified, if you choose to go this route.

Comment: This is definitely the better solution if the shapefiles are coming from tigris (or can be obtained that way), as it gives the same results and with more control over resolution without going through the intermediate steps of large data frames and lots of processing time to reduce them (ie the method using rmapshaper::ms_simplify).